# Passing and using an optional mask within subroutine

Tags: fortran

I pass an optional mask to a subroutine. Within this routine I then have many statements of the kind

```
...
if (present(Mask)) then
  where(Mask)
    y(:) = A(:)*B(:)
  end where
else
  y(:) = A(:)*B(:)
end if
...
```

This is very ugly in regards of code duplication. Are there any advices to do this in a better way? I have many statements like this in my code and I need to perform the operations on whole arrays.

Edit:
At least a part of the problem can be solved through elemental functions. Because I have the same operations on the right side I can write

```
...
if (present(Mask)) then
  where(Mask)
    y(:) = multiply(A(:),B(:))
  end where
else
  y(:) = multiply(A(:),B(:))
end if
...
elemental real function multiply(a,b)
  real, intent(in) :: a,b
  multiply = a*b
end function
```

This way, I have at least a single place for the operations.

Comment: There is discussion around [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37723973/3157076). Does anything in there suit you?

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. It seems to me that there is no straight forward solution and my problem is very similar. I guess that's ok for me to know for now.

Answer (score 2):

There is the option (pun intended) to no use optional arguments, and instead, write a generic interface.  For example, instead of writing

```
subroutine bar(arg0, opt)
  integer, intent(inout) :: arg0
  integer, intent(in), optional :: opt
  arg0 = int(4 * atan(1.))
  if (present(opt)) arg0 = arg0 + opt
module foo
```

You can do

```
interface bar
  module procedure bar0
  module procedure bar1
end interface bar

contains

  subroutine bar0(arg0)
     integer, intent(inout) :: arg0
     arg0 = int(4 * atan(1.))
  end subroutine bar0

  subroutine bar1(arg0, opt)
     integer, intent(inout) :: arg0
     integer, intent(in) :: opt
     arg0 = arg0 + opt
  end subroutine bar1

end module foo

program bah
  use foo
  integer :: a0 = 1, a1 = 42
  call bar(a0)
  print *, a0
  call bar(a0, a1)
  print *, a0
end program bah
```

One advantage that you may gain from this approach is that bar0
and bar1 may allow a compiler to do a better job of optimizing
the code.  The `if (present(opt))` construct may get in the way.

Comment: This is a very nice idea, especially from a performance viewpoint. Unfortunately, in my case I pass this Mask through many subroutines which would mean I would also need to write interfaces for all these routines. Additionally, I would still have code duplications for the right sides. But it led me to another idea - I could use elemental functions, than I would at least get rid of the duplicate assignments from the right side.

Comment: Yes, the ability to pass `optional` arguments down a call chain is a nice feature.  When I do use `optional` arguments, I structure the code to minimize the `if (present(arg))` testing (i.e., typically two blocks of code).